# Variable can be not defined

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I have this piece of code:

```
from django.db import transaction

with transaction.atomic():
    try:
        variable = 1
    except Exception:
        raise Exception()

print(variable)
```

And pycharm (2018.1.2) tells me that `variable` in `print` function `can be not defined`. In which case it can happen? Or is it a pycharm bug?

Comment: @DanielRoseman It's just an example, in original code where i discovered this i catched another exception and raised different :) Here i just simplified it... catched and raised exception can be differ.

Comment: @AntoineLB But in case of exception we will never reach `print` function, it should not be a problem as far as i understand.

Comment: The problem is that the `with` could theoretically swallow the exception. `transaction.atomic` doesn't do that but pycharm doesn't know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in which case it can happen?

If the context manager swallows the exception, and if you replace the `raise` statement with anything else that don't interrupt the execution flow before it reaches the `print(variable)` line.

As a rule of thumb: code that does not depend on a condition (in the most general meaning) should not use names which are conditionaly defined, and only the code belonging to the same branch as the one that defines a name should access this name.

Even if you "know" that *in the current implementation* this name will never be accessed if not defined (as in your example), any even minor implementation change can break this precondition and you might not necessarily notice it, nor have a suffisant unittest coverage to make sure your tests will catch the issue. I've seen this happening often enough and sometimes the bug only surfaces months after the change (typically in error handling code for some pretty rare pathological corner case).

To make a long story short, unconditionnally defining the name with some sentinel value (`None` or anything else that makes sense) before the conditionnal part(s) will make sure your code won't break unexpectedly after what was supposed to be a minor code change.